# How to solve max call size stack exceeded when compiling solidity?

Tags: solidity

I am using this - https://github.com/ericxtang/browser-solc

The code works when I select a new compiler version but I continually get a stack error when I try and run the same version. Does anyone have any ideas how to solve this?

I have this code -

```
document.getElementById("compile-output").value = "";
    var result = compiler.compile(getSourceCode(), optimize);
    var stringResult = JSON.stringify(result);
    document.getElementById("compile-output").value = stringResult;

    var bytecode = result.contracts.greeter.bytecode;
    var abi = result.contracts.greeter.interface;

    web3 = new Web3(web3.currentProvider);

    // Our future code here..
     web3.eth.defaultAccount = web3.eth.accounts[0];
```

```
Uncaught RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded
    at Object.pgb [as dynCall_viiiiii] (VM380 soljson-v0.4.25-nightly.2018.8.16+commit.a9e7ae29.js:12)
    at invoke_viiiiii (VM380 soljson-v0.4.25-nightly.2018.8.16+commit.a9e7ae29.js:1)
    at Array.hwa (VM380 soljson-v0.4.25-nightly.2018.8.16+commit.a9e7ae29.js:13)
    at Object.acb [as dynCall_vi] (VM380 soljson-v0.4.25-nightly.2018.8.16+commit.a9e7ae29.js:12)
    at invoke_vi (VM380 soljson-v0.4.25-nightly.2018.8.16+commit.a9e7ae29.js:1)
    at Array.pua (VM380 soljson-v0.4.25-nightly.2018.8.16+commit.a9e7ae29.js:10)
    at Object.Thb [as dynCall_iii] (VM380 soljson-v0.4.25-nightly.2018.8.16+commit.a9e7ae29.js:12)
    at invoke_iii (VM380 soljson-v0.4.25-nightly.2018.8.16+commit.a9e7ae29.js:1)
    at Array.nua (VM380 soljson-v0.4.25-nightly.2018.8.16+commit.a9e7ae29.js:10)
    at Object.mib [as dynCall_iiiiii] (VM380 soljson-v0.4.25-nightly.2018.8.16+commit.a9e7ae29.js:12)
```

Comment: How did you solve? I saw that by downgrading from nodejs 12 to 8 works. Also, my smart contract is very small so can't be that

Answer (score 1):

There is only one way to solve it - lowering the complexity of your contract. EVM max stack is 1024 so if your contract is too complex it will exceed that during deployment and execution will halt.

If you absolutely cannot take some variables out, consider splitting your contract into multiple contracts.